# Woocommerce disable setup wizard

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am attempting to install quite a few woocommerce sites. I have code that inserts the relevant setup info into the options table, and all works well.

So I don't need/want the setup wizard to fire up at all.
Is there a way to disable it?

I've looked through class WC_Admin_Setup_Wizard, and there don't appear to be any hooks or filters. And nothing in the woo documentation that I can see.

Comment: You didn't look very hard, then. There's a filter hook right in the `__construct()` function that seems fit for what you're trying to do: [woocommerce_enable_setup_wizard](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Admin_Setup_Wizard.html#55).

Comment: well I spotted it but it didn't seems to do anything when I set add_filter( 'woocommerce_enable_setup_wizard', function( $true ) { return false; } );

Comment: Had code in wrong place all working. long day code blindness. Thanks for commenting @cabrerahector.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question, @Stephen. Make sure you mention what the problem was in detail so other readers in the future know how to fix it too.